# The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new on ASP.NET MVC, I have a project and when I puslish It on IIS, It throw an exception like this:

"An unhandled win32 exception occured in w3wp.exe The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions. To debug this proces, the JIT debugger must be run as an administrator. Would you like to debug the proces?"

I try to set DefaultAppPool Properties to Local System but it not work!
How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: For the benefit of searchers, this SO post had the solution for me - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12427014/852806

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like your application is causing the IIS worker process to crash. In order to get to the bottom of this you can do one or more of the following:

1. Check the Event Viewer to see why the application is crashing. If you filter the Application log by the ASP.NET 2.0 and 4.0 sources you should see a bunch of warnings indicating what exception caused the crash.
2. Attach to the process using Visual Studio and determine what exception is being thrown. This will give you the most detailed information.

Changing security privileges on the application pool is unlikely to help you here; the reason the JIT dialog is appearing is because the application is crashing and you are running in a different security context to your interactive session!

Post more information about the crash if you want help getting to the bottom of it.

Cheers