# App crashes when after sending Azure push notification C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, push-notification, unhandled-exception

I'm using Azure push notifications SDK v1.0.8 and everytime my code calls that framework's logic it crashes and Windows shows a Pop-up error window which says w3wp process stopped. How can I solve that?
The code executes well because the notification appears in the mobile device.

Pop-up error window: [image: Pop-up error window]

My code is something like this (a separate thread to avoid affecting current code execution flow):

```
private async void SendNotificationsAsync(MobileNotification notification)
    {
        await GetHub().SendTemplateNotificationAsync(notification.templatePorperties, notification.tag);
    }
```

The error in VS2015 is:
"System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Have you click the debug w3wp.exe with the administrator account? In my opinion, we should know more about the information about the crash. Besides, I suggest you could also check the global.asax to find if it has exception as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186157/the-just-in-time-debugger-was-launched-without-necessary-security-permission/12427014#12427014) says.

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT I did but it shows a black screen which says "break state" :/

Comment: Could you please tell me which code shows the NullReferenceException?

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT I was finally able to fix it by using: Task.Run(() => GetHub().SendTemplateNotificationAsync